# sql: intersect in sql (join probability)

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I am struggling with a SQL question and I just can't figure it out. I have to count the number of people who like two types of foods.

I have one table that shows the user_ids and a column that indicates what type of foods they like. the ids could be repetitive since one person might like more than one food.
I also have a table that shows the user_ids and a column that indicates what types of drinks they like. Again, the user ids could be repetitive.

With this two table, I have to create a table that counts the number of people who like a type food, and count the number of people who like a type of drink and count the number of people who like the pairs. Below is an example of what I am expecting to have:

```
foods .  --------- drinks --------- count_food ------- count_drink -------count_combination
hamburger          coke .              17 .              67                  21
pizza              coke .              45                67                  8
chicken            coke                21                67                  25
```

So far, I have created the foods, drinks, count_food and count_drink columns. I used the cross join function to create the foods and drinks column and used the count function to fill in the count_food and count drink columns. However, I am stuck in the count_combination column. I just don't know how to make that. Could this be done by the cross validation join?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have provided your desired output in the question, I managed to recreate your case with sample data.

In order to achieve the final result, I have done all the steps you mentioned: *count of people who just like one drink, count for people who just like one food* then *count of people who like the drink and the food.*

Below is the sample data and the steps I took,

```
#sample data for food
WITH food AS(
SELECT 1 AS user_ids, "hamburguer" AS foods UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS user_ids, "hamburguer" AS foods UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS user_ids, "hamburguer" AS foods UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS user_ids, "pizza" AS foods UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS user_ids, "pizza" AS foods UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS user_ids, "chicken" AS foods 
),

#sample data for drink
drink AS(
SELECT 1 AS user_ids, "coke" AS drinks UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS user_ids, "coke" AS drinks UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS user_ids, "coke" AS drinks UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS user_ids, "coke" AS drinks UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS user_ids, "coke" AS drinks 
),
#count how many people like each type of food
count_foods AS (
SELECT COUNT(foods) AS count_foods, foods FROM food GROUP BY foods
),
#count how many people like each type of drink
count_drinks AS(
SELECT COUNT(drinks) AS count_drinks, drinks FROM drink GROUP BY drinks
),
#making all the possible combinations between foods and drinks with CROSS JOIN
food_drink_only AS (
SELECT foods, drinks, count_foods, count_drinks FROM count_foods a CROSS JOIN count_drinks b
),
#people who like one food and a drink, for ex.: user_ids = 1 likes hamburguer and coke
like_both AS (
SELECT  COUNT(user_ids) AS count_both, foods, drinks FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_ids, foods FROM food) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_ids, drinks FROM drink) USING(user_ids) GROUP BY  2,3
)
#Using left join with foods and drinks as primary keys because all the combinations (fodds, drinks) came from the CROSS JOIN
#and are in the left table
SELECT a.foods,a.drinks,a.count_foods,a.count_drinks, b.count_both FROM food_drink_only a
LEFT JOIN like_both b ON a.foods = b.foods AND a.drinks=b.drinks
```

And the output,

```
Row foods   drinks  count_foods count_drinks    count_both
1   hamburguer  coke    3   5   2
2   pizza   coke    2   5   1
3   chicken coke    1   5   null
```

First, notice that the [CROSS JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#cross_join) gives us all the possible combinations between `foods` and `drinks`. For this reason, when creating the final output [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join) is used. Then, pay attention that within the `like_both` table there will be ***2 users who like coke and hamburguer, 1 user who likes coke and pizza and 0 users who like coke and chicken***. For this reason, the fields `foods` and `drinks` were used as primary keys to join this table with `food_drink_only` table. Hence, the data was placed with the right *food and drink combination.*